# Square Root to 2 Decimal places

Tags: python, decimal

I've been trying to do some homework and was getting on fine until I came across a particular task.

The Task is: Ask the user to enter an integer that is over 500. Work out the square root of that number and display it to 2 decimal places.

My current code is below I have managed to make it do the square root part but it is not displaying it to 2 decimal places.

```
import math
number = float(input("Please Input a number over 500 and i will work out the square root of that number and display it to 2 decimal places! "))

if number < 500:
    print("That number is not above 500!")
else:
    print(math.sqrt(round(number,2)))
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ?

Comment: You round *before* taking the square root. Note you should give a [mcve] **as text**.

Comment: Your code as text please.

Comment: For example: `round(sqrt(600),2)`.

Comment: just print it to 2 decimal places `"{num:0.2f}".format(num=sqrt(x))` ... rounding simply rounds the value it will still probably print more that two decimal places

Comment: Just print using 2 decimal places? Have you tried it `print "{:.2f}".format(math.sqrt(round(number,2)))`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In the future, please post your code as formatted text rather than an image. This makes it easier to read as well as copy and paste into our editors to try out.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> format(math.sqrt(500), '.2f')
'22.36'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the format() function

```
format(math.sqrt(num), '.2f')
```